# How to disable creation of fooX lists in IPSet

Tags: debian, fail2ban, ipset, shorewall

I installed fail2ban, ipset and shorewall on Debian 12 to protect my server from bruteforce. After changing the rules and restart shorewall, fooX**** sheets are created in ipset. Also i see this problem in Astra Linux (based on Debian 10)

I also have a server on Ubuntu 20. There are no such problems there

Configured this way

fail2ban/jail.d/main.conf

```
[ssh]
enabled = true
filter = sshd
banaction = shorewall-ipset-proto6
...
```

shorewall/shorewall.conf

```
BLACKLIST="ALL"
IP_FORWARDING=Yes
```

Other parameters remain unchanged

I use command `ipset -L` and in addition to my f2b-ssh sheet see this

```
Name: fooX7216
Type: hash:ip
Revision: 5
Header: family inet hashsize 1024 maxelem 65536 bucketsize 12 initval 0x928f0dc8
Size in memory: 200
References: 0
Number of entries: 0
Members:
```

How it disable?

**UPDATE**

I found why this happens

I checked the iptables version and saw that nf_tables was used (`iptables v1.8.7 (nf_tables)`). I changed the alternative (`update-alternatives --config iptables`) to "legacy" and the problem went away

If you have any ideas why this could happen (creating fooX sheets when using nftables) I'd be glad to listen